# Filter out object section that the button is attached to

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

I am having trouble filtering out objects in an array. The code I have when one button is clicked on the whole array is filtered. I want to where I clicked, that object is deleted from the array. I have tried the splice, and filtering methods but I end up with the same results as the whole array gets deleted instead of that one item. How can I target just that one item?

```
function removeItem(btns, id) {

    btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

            let newArr = shoppingList.filter((item, i) => {
                return item.id !== item.id
            })

            shoppingList = newArr
            cartMenuItems.innerHTML = newArr
            cartItemCount.innerText = newArr.length
            return newArr
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: You're comparing the `item.id` to itself, and since they will never not be equal it always returns `false`. I'm assuming you actually want to compare the button.id(or other pertinent attribute) to the item.id instead.

Comment: @pilchard Hi, pilchard. It still does the same thing if I compare it to something else. It deletes the entire array or returns the original array.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud get the id of element from click event and next may be get new array with map()

```
let element = e.target //for example
let newArr = shoppingList.map((item, i) => {
            if (item.id === element.id) continue
            return item
        })
```

it code returns all array and aborts your element from page